# Login to OWA using other domain that portal.microsoftonline.com

Tags: exchange-server, office365, outlook-web-app

I have problem with login to OWA using fore example mail.domain.pl. I try to use this domain to login to OWA but i can't find URL's address which redirect to OWA login page.

Any solution?

Thanks,

Skrzypolus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configure Sign-In URLs for Outlook Web App:**
http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/hh292586.aspx